# mongodump by date / find() in dumped data

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

1. How to dump all collections by date? If my records hasn't timestamp field?

   > Fields: _id, name, email, carnumber... etc.
2. And how to look/find() in archived/dumped database?
   I need to create search mechanism, for searching in archive

Answer (score 2):

1. You can pass a query to mongodump that will make it dump only a portion of your data. If you can't make a query that finds a required portion of data, then you're out of luck.
2. Result of mongodump is a collection of bson files. They are not directly queryable. But you can load them into another database and query that. Or you can use `mongoexport` utility that creates JSON documents. JSON is a little bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Although what Sergio says is broadly true, let me expand a bit:

First, You mention using _id - if that is an ObjectID (the default), then it contains a timestamp - the first 4 bytes are a unix style timestamp:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

Next, the problem with using mongoexport is that JSON does not preserve all BSON types (http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) - BSON has more types than JSON does and so storing as JSON can be problematic unless you have rules to re-import

If you keep the data in BSON format there is the bsondump to inspect things as-is in the files:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-bsondump

Or, if you had an "archive" MongoDB instance, you could just use mongodump/mongorestore, which works directly with the BSON files and does not have the JSON issues seen with mongoexport etc.:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodumpandmongorestore